# vlaue of checkbox to database in vue laravel

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel, database, vue.js

i have this input:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
<label for="patymentTerms">Payment Terms</label>
<b-form-checkbox id="patymentTerms" :checked="true" switch v-model="rForm.payment_terms" />
</div>
```

and this is the data:

```
data() {
return {
  rForm: {
    payment_terms: "",
  },
};
```

},

i am able to store data and other inputs in database but i'm a bit confused of how can i return false or true to of this input

Comment: A checkbox value is only ever "On" (which you can change to anything you like e.g. true) or empty. there is not really a false. remove `:checked` since you are using v-model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

I forgot to change the input to boolean in MySQL and Controller

so this solved my problem:

View:

```
payment_terms: Boolean,
```

Controller:

```
'payment_terms' => 'required|boolean',
```

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
data() {
   return {
     rForm: {
        payment_terms: 0,
      },
    };
```

on on your controller:

```
$payment_terms = $request->payment_terms == 1 ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by using only `v-model`.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      rForm: {
        payment_terms: false,
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getCheckboxValue() {
        console.log(this.rForm.payment_terms);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <label for="patymentTerms">Payment Terms</label>
  <b-form-checkbox v-model="rForm.payment_terms" @change="getCheckboxValue" />
</div>
```